# How build and install Android SystemUi

Tags: android, android-source

I want to change some element in SystemUI, not only colors and resources, but also possibly change some behavior directly in the part of AOSP - systemui part.

[Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/libs/systemui/) from google

[Link](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/tree/cdf75c3cc82c8a3ea431f7d5b0c117601a8e6a33/packages/SystemUI) from old mirror

I can download sources, i can change code source, but how i can build only SystemUI part into .apk file and and install in to my device?

P.S.: I have keys for sign, i have device, i have aosp, but i want work with only SystemUI part, if possible separately as a separate module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need full source code of AOSP version.

Then you can build  SystemUI with mm command.

Answer (score 0):

From full source of AOSP folder

Instead of build full image by make -jX, you can build system ui only by command

```
make SystemUI
```